# Is "Is there a tool to convert PHP from higher version to lower version" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've posted [a question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18368/356) earlier which was downvoted without any comments.

From the FAQ, the question seems to be exactly the kind of questions that are on-topic. I've even mentioned the "specific requirements" as https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour so suggests.

Is [*"Is there a tool to convert PHP from higher version to lower version"*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18368/356) on-topic?

If not, how should it be edited to be on-topic? Specifically, what is this site looking for for it to be on-topic?

Comment: Note that downvoting does not necessarily mean that the question would be off-topic (users may downvote for various reasons, including no reason at all). Currently, it has 1 close vote, giving the close reason "too broad".

Comment: To me it looks fine (and, as unor already indicated, is perfectly on-topic). It might well be I took it easier to see what you're after, as I'm in a comparable situation (in one project I participate we were discussing compatibility for 5.3, as that's the latest version Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ships in its repos – and we had some 5.4-introduced notations in, like `$foo = bar()[1]`). I cannot see anything wrong with it. I also often wish downvoters were forced to leave a reason (and be it something multiple-choice, so we had an indicator at least)...

Comment: Ah: To improve it, there might be something you can add. Should that conversion tool be written in PHP, too? If so: which version should it be capable running under? If not: what OS must the tool be capable running under?

Comment: @Izzy, OS yes, looks like I've missed that part. Have edited it in.